# How to create two dataframes from a given dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have the following data frame:

[image]

I want to create two data frames such that for any row if column `Actual` is equal to column `Predicted` then the value in both columns goes in one data frame otherwise both columns go in another data frame.

For example, row 0,1,2 goes in dataframe named `correct_df` and row 245,247 goes in dataframe named `incorect_df`

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean indexing:

```
m = df['Actual'] == df['Predicted']
correct_df = df.loc[m]
incorrect_df = df.loc[~m]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
df_cor = df.loc[(df['Actual'] == df['Predicted'])]    
df_incor = df2 = df.loc[(df['Actual']!= df['Predicted'])]
```

And use `reset_index` if you want a new index.